# I have a problem where sudo does not work can you help me?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, sudo

Basically I have been following steps on [this website](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/ubuntu-hardware-permissions-how-to-set-ownership-of-drive-or-partition-internal-external-hard-disks/) to mount my hard-drive properly and now each time I try to follow the first step it says:

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

It used to work but it used to say I do not have permission even though I am logged on as root.

Comment: Does `sudo` work with other commands requiring uid=0? e.g. `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Did you maybe mistype the `chown -R` command in the instructions, and change the ownerships of some system files? what does `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo` return?

Comment: oh, we overlapped, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, could be that you made an error previously? Looks a lot like [this story](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-sudo-installed-setuid-root-4175438614/).

Running `chown -R` is a bit dangerous when used wrongly.